# Google My Business API - Response "Method not found" 404

Tags: oauth2-playground

Just got access to the Google My Business API and have been following the instructions found here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/get-started

### Project Info

PROJECT_ID=twocents-reviews

PROJECT_NUMBER=705754565185

I'm trying to use the OAuth 2.0 Playground to send my first Google My Business API request to https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts, and this is the response I get (below).

### Response

```
GET /v3/accounts HTTP/1.1
Host: mybusiness.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer [**** REDACTED ****]
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-length: 100
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-goog-trace-id: 6748d818415fd6349e9763a87acb707e
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 23:28:51 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "status": "NOT_FOUND", 
    "message": "Method not found.", 
    "code": 404
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?

Comment: Yes, I got a response directly from Google and it's resolved. It just took some approvals from Google.

Comment: @BakerStreetSystems It would be really helpful to myself and others coming across this if you'd answer your own question and post a link to where you used to contact Google and what they said the issue was...what did you ask/tell them? I'm experiencing this exact issue

Answer (score 2):

Google just hadn't finished the setup process yet. All I needed to do was wait a bit longer for the API to work for me.